# Java script file reader How can i make this a multi file reader?

Tags: javascript

I am not the best at JS but I need it for my site, i want to be able to read the files that i select.

this is the input.

```
  <form name="filUpload" action="" method="post" enctype="form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="name">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Image upload start -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Top">Top</label>
                                <input onchange="readURL(this, '#thumbnail-Top');"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Bottom">Bottom</label>
                                <input onchange="readURL(this);"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Left">Left</label>
                                <input onchange="readURL(this);"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile"/>
                            </div>
                                <label for="Right">Right</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input onchange="readURL(this);"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Image upload end -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="submit" style="" class="btn btn-success m-3" value="Submit" name="btn_type_send" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And this is where the pictures gets displayed The id="thumbnail-..." is the one used in the script below. i know it's not right in the script but that is where i have my problem i think. 
    I'll explain in the script part.

```
    <div class="">
           <div class="card m-2">
           <h4 class="card-header text-center">Images</h4>

                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="flex-fill">
                        <h5 class="card-header">Top</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Top" src="#" style=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-fill">
                        <h5 class="card-header">Bottom</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Bottom" src="#" style=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-fill">
                        <h5 class="card-header">Left</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Left" src="#" style=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-fill">
                        <h5 class="card-header">Right</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Right" src="#" style=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

           </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the script. What I think is my problem is that i need to select multiple ids, and i have no idea how to do so. i want to be able to select 1 image for each category "top,bottom,Left,Right". And if possible, i have to use it on a other side as well, where there only is 3 categories "because the sides are identical".

The #thumbnail is the id i was talking about.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input, id) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Examples would really be appreciated!

Comment: Step 1: Fix your HTML. IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Why the -1. something I didnt explain right?

Comment: If you want to keep the element the preview gets output to dynamic, then you could pass the id to it as a second parameter to your readURL function.

Comment: Do you want to select _one_ image with each input field, or _multiple_ in each field? (Cause currently your file input elements have the `multiple` attribute set, not sure if that’s what you actually want here.)

Comment: do you mean like this,  function readURL (input, #id,) ?

Comment: one image each input field

Comment: ohh ill change that now

Comment: No, variable names in JavaScript can not begin with a `#`. Something like `function readURL(input, id)`, called using `onchange="readURL(this, '#foo');"`

Comment: Ohh thanks ill try it out

Comment: hmm doesnt work, think it has something to do with the #thumbnail in the script

Comment: Well that is of course the place where you need to make use of the new parameter that you passed to your function now - `$(id)`

Comment: ohh oka! now one picture is showing, but when i try select one more it doesnt show.

Comment: You mean in the next input field, or …? Did you modify the ids in the onchange attribute accordingly?

Comment: i can try edit the code to what i have now :)

Comment: Looks like you only modified the onchange on the first input field so far, you need to do that for the rest of them as well.

Comment: think i did that before, but ill test it again

Comment: sry i forgot "," it worked perfectly

Comment: Thanks alot! for the help ill mark this as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer was given by  @misorude**

The input needed correct onchange="readURL();" like so:

```
  <form name="filUpload" action="" method="post" enctype="form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Navn</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="name">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Image upload start -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="top">Top billede</label>
                            <input onchange="readURL(this, '#thumbnail-Top');"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile" id="file" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="bottom">Bund billede</label>
                            <input onchange="readURL(this, '#thumbnail-Bottom');"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile" id="file" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="venstre-side">venstre-side</label>
                            <input onchange="readURL(this, '#thumbnail-Left');"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile" id="file" />
                        </div>
                            <label for="hoejre-side">højre-side</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input onchange="readURL(this, '#thumbnail-Right');"  class="form-control-file" type="file" name="userfile" id="file" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Image upload end -->
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="submit" style="" class="btn btn-success m-3" value="Submit" name="btn_type_send" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Where the image should be displayed looks like this "its not really styled".

```
<div class="card m-2">
       <h4 class="card-header text-center">Images</h4>

                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="flex-fill">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Top</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Top" src="#" style=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-fill">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Bottom</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Bottom" src="#" style=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-fill">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Left</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Left" src="#" style=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-fill">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Right</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="card-img text-center" alt="" id="thumbnail-Right" src="#" style=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

       </div>
```

And the script looks like this, the function readURL was corrected, and the $(id) was corrected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input, id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(id).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```